# Refactoring react app to separate UI (a la MVC)?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, chat-gpt-4

We are working on an Open Source (AGPL) Chrome extension: [Digital Assistant Client](https://github.com/Digital-Assistant/Digital_Assistant_Client)

We have a React application which is developed without using redux. We have had multiple requests for custom UI. We want to separate the UI and functionality - like an MVC architecture. We are considering Redux (open to suggestions here).

How can I achieve this conversion using redux context with GPT tools? I am not an expert at prompting but tried using codieum, sourcegraph cody and refact{dot}ai tools but they are not able to convert the existing code to redux context.

I basically want to go file by file and use prompts to change each individual file, review the code before merging it back.